# ctype_digit - strange behaviour

Tags: php

I have a `array`, and the first `13` values are `integer`.

Now, if I do :

```
array_push($pos1, 100);
```

I'll aspect that value `14` is also an `Integer`. But in fact, doing :

```
echo ctype_digit($pos1[12])." - ".ctype_digit($pos1[13]);
```

The output is `1 -`

This is the print_r, as requested :

```
Array ( [0] => 0 
        [1] => 1 
        [2] => 2 
        [3] => 3 
        [4] => 4 
        [5] => 5 
        [6] => 6 
        [7] => 7 
        [8] => 8 
        [9] => 9 
        [10] => 10 
        [11] => 11 
        [12] => 12 
        [13] => 100 )
```

Why?

Comment: Can you show a `print_r` of the full array?

Comment: What `$pos1` contains before using `ctype_digit` ?

Comment: try `print_r($pos1)`, what does it print?

Comment: Edited the topic : You can show the print_r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (in fact) a little bit strange, but [ctype_digit()](http://php.net/ctype-digit) strictly requires a string

```
echo ctype_digit((string) $pos1[12])." - ".ctype_digit((string) $pos1[13]); // "1 - 1"
```

I dont know, why PHP doesnt cast it into a string.

However, the `1` in the output comes from the type-cast, because `ctype_digit()` returns a boolean

```
echo true; // "1"
echo false; // ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes because `ctype_digit()` function strictly requires a string. You are getting output `1-` just because PHP treats its

```
echo ctype_digit($pos1[12])." - ".ctype_digit($pos1[13]);
```

as

`echo ctype_digit($pos1[12]);`      //Giving output *TRUE*

```
echo " - " ;  //Giving output * - *
echo ctype_digit($pos1[13]);
```

**FALSE** because In array the first 13 values are integer and 14th one is not an integer .