# Why does ctype_digit(0) return FALSE

Tags: php

`ctype_digit(0)` returns `FALSE`

`ctype_digit("0")` returns `TRUE`

As per PHP's type conversion 0 should be promoted to string "0". But when calling as 0 or 1 or 2 it is not getting promoted to an string. Why?

Comment: Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962529/ctype-digit-strange-behaviour. I'd be interested in knowing why this exception for type conversion is allowed in PHP. Why doesn't php manual lists this specificity for ctype_digit!

Comment: Sorry got it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php the reason is listed in the bottom which is not there in my php chm manual.

Answer (score 10):

```
$numeric_string = '42';
$integer        = 42;
ctype_digit($numeric_string);  // true
ctype_digit($integer);         // false (ASCII 42 is the * character)
```

ASCII `0` is `NULL` , so it returns false.